# Ordenar Group by de Pandas de mayor a menor + problema al pasar grafico a PNG

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy leyendo un csv y graficando en Python usando el siguiente codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('Direccion del archivo Csv', header = 0, sep=';')
g = data.groupby(["SUBDETERMINANTE"])["POSITIVAS", "POSIBLES"].sum()
```

*1) ¿Como ordenar g groupby de mayor a menor en base al campo positivas para que al hacer el grafico esten en ese orden?*

```
g.plot(kind='barh', legend='Reverse')
plt.title(u'ANALISIS DE SUBDETERMINANTES', size = 12.0)
plt.xlabel(u'Suma', size = 12.0)
plt.ylabel('SubDeterminantes', size = 12.0)
fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
print ("Current size:", fig_size)
fig_size[0] = 10.0
fig_size[1] = 15.0
plt.savefig('detalle')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mostrar la grafica con los datos de mayor a menor segun el total de positivas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) Al finalizar el grafico lo descargo en PNG, como puedo hacer para que se muestre el nombre entero?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**SOLUCIONADO GRACIAS A LA RESPUESTA DE ABULAFIA**

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('Direccion donde esta el archivo csv', header = 0, sep=';')
g = data.groupby(["SUBDETERMINANTE"])["POSITIVAS", 
"POSIBLES"].sum().sort_values(by="POSITIVAS")
g.plot(kind='barh', legend='Reverse')
plt.title(u'ANALISIS DE SUBDETERMINANTES', size = 12.0)
plt.xlabel(u'Suma', size = 12.0)
plt.ylabel('SubDeterminantes', size = 12.0)
fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
print ("Current size:", fig_size)
fig_size[0] = 10.0
fig_size[1] = 15.0
plt.savefig('detalle', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[Documentación sort_values para dataframe en Pandas:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al no disponer de tus datos no puedo verificar si mi respuesta es correcta. En todo caso, creo que sería de la forma siguiente:

### 1. Ordenar el dataframe

Los dataframes tienen el método `sort_values()`. Prueba por tanto lo siguiente:

```
g = (data.groupby(["SUBDETERMINANTE"])["POSITIVAS", "POSIBLES"]
     .sum()
     .sort_values(by="POSITIVAS"))
```

(los paréntesis con que rodeé todo son un truco para poder partir la expresión en
varias líneas, para mejor legibilidad, puedes ponerlo todo en una sola línea y sin los paréntesis, si prefieres)

### 2. Exportación de imagen

No me queda claro cómo la exportas, si mediante `savefig()` o a través de alguna opcion de tu interfaz gráfica de usuario. Si es con `savefig()` a menudo los problemas de este estilo se resuelven pasándole el parámetro `bbox_inches='tight'`

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto lo que si y para ver cual es la opcion correcta luego de g = abris un parentesis y al final lo cerras, en mi codigo yo no abro parentesis ahi, tiene que ir o es indistinto? Yo lo tengo asi : g = data.groupby(["SUBDETERMINANTE"])["POSITIVAS", "POSIBLES"].sum().sort_values(by="POSITIVAS")

Comment: @Juan En la respuesta aclaré la misión de ese paréntesis. En pandas es frecuente encadenar métodos así: `df.metodo1().metodo2().metodo3()...` etc, lo que puede dar lugar a líneas muy largas. Para mejorar la legibilidad se puede partir por líneas antes de cada `.`, de modo que cada línea sea una de las llamadas encadenadas. Los paréntesis encerrando todo son un truco para que Python admita esa expresión multi-linea.